# CSS - mix-blend-mode: difference confusion

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

I've been looking into mix-blend-mode in CSS which seems like a powerful property!
However, I'm very confused as to how this actually works. I'm having unpredictable results.
Take this codepen as an example:

https://codepen.io/KingKabir/pen/ONyPeg

The background of the body is set to a dark color, while every other section has a background set to white.

```
body { background-color: #000 }
section:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: #FFF}
```

Now try to change the background color of the **body** to white, and notice how the menu doesn't change it's color to black. What is going on here? Both sections have the same background-color?

If you set the background color of the first section specifically to white, it works as intended. But not if the first section has no background-color and the body is set to white. Shouldn't the results be the same?

I'm having this exact issue on a project I'm working on and I can't figure out what is going on. Edit: I'm using Google Chrome 83.0.4103.106

Edit: Here is an image of what I mean
[image]

Comment: Hmm mix-blend-mode does affect the objects contents, not background. So if you make body green, the menu-*text* gets red, if you make it black, the menu-*text* gets white and so on. If I scroll to a another section I can even get the menu splitted into one half of the text in black letters and one half in white.. everything looks how I would expect, so maybe you have to describe more precisely what you expect and maybe add images what you see.

Comment: Sure, I updated the post with an image of what I mean :)
Basically, both the body and the second section have the same background color of white. But the mix-mode doesn't seem to apply correctly. The entire menu should have black text and menu icon.

Comment: This... feels like a bug in Chrome, if you set the `sections` background to white it correctly calculates the difference and shows black text. I've had a look around and as far as I can tell, it looks like they have fixed it in most cases, but the issue remains when the page is iframed (like in codepen) [Bug thread here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=711955) It also mentions adding a background-color to the `html` is a possible workaround.

Comment: Aha! In my project, there's an iframe as well. I will look at the workaround! Thank you! This was driving me crazy! :D